# Can I sort files in Dolphin into date order on Kubuntu 12.04.01?

Tags: kubuntu, dolphin, sort

Can I sort files in Dolphin into date order on Kubuntu 12.04.01?

It was suggested (can't remember where) that Nepomuk would do this. If this is so, how do I enable Nepomuk. The application appears to have been installed, but clicking it does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch into **Details view mode** and then you will be able to click on the top of the **Date** column.